# Simulating a second, hidden physics scene into the future on a single frame to predict the trajectories of planets?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scene-manager

I want to simulate the trajectories of planets in a seperate scene to find out where they will be in the future. I drew a [quick diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBRoH.png) to demonstrate.

Is there a way to simulate 2 scenes separately, hiding one but showing the other? I tried [this](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/multi-scene-physics#5fb96f14edbc2a7ff2348497) which says they don't interact with each other, but when I tried it they still collided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a way, if you put all "hidden" objects, like planets on a reparate layer in unity[image]

and disable collisions between that and any other layers in the
edit/project setting/physics[image]

This way those objects won't have any effect on the rest of your scene.

To visually hide the objects simply disable the rendering of that layer in your scene camera. And that's it, if hope this was helpful.

Comment: Would that allow for pausing the visible objects's physics, running the invisible objects's physics for (the equivalent of) a couple seconds worth of frames, getting their positions and passing them back to the visible objects, then resuming the visible objects's physics, all of that in a single frame?

Comment: I believe what you're looking for is "patched conics".

Comment: Your approach sounds quite complicated, just a guess, but wouldn't proportionately increasing your objects' velocity achieve the same thing?